# My program runs using panda 1.3.4 but errors with 1.4.2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, multiplication

My program runs using panda 1.3.4 but errors with 1.4.2. Below is the code fragment.  DataFrame mul works in 1.3.4 but not 1.4.2.  I am getting a type error when using 1.4.2 which does not make intuitive sense.

```py
initial_appraisal = engine_value.loc[:]['initial_appraised_value']
minimum_balance_table = minimum_balance_table.mul(initial_appraisal.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC remove `loc[:]`:

```
initial_appraisal = engine_value['initial_appraised_value']
```

Also test if nencessary use:

```
minimum_balance_table = minimum_balance_table.mul(initial_appraisal.to_numpy())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Once I added ".values" to the end of engine_values['initial_appraisal_value'] , it worked.